# Make a custom nomalization layer in Keras (per features)

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I try to make a custom loss function in Keras.

I want to create a model that performs the following normalize expression in 10 feature units.

[image]

Each node in normalization layer perform the following normalization.

[image]

When 80 units of output are grouped into 10 units, the sum of squares of 10 units must be 1.

For example, the output is a1, a2, ..., a80. 
If a1 = 10, a2 = 0, a3 = 0, ..., a9 = 0 and a10 = 10, then squared sum = 200.
Finally, a1 = 10 / sqrt (200), a2 = 0, ..., a9 = 0, a10 = 10 / sqrt (200).
After that, I need to calculate the error magnitude.

So, I add a `Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=-1))` layer at the end of model, and use loss='mse'.

To do this, I have to fix the weight of the connected part of the norm layer and the previous layerto 1 and I wonder how to do that.

Also, I need to connect each node of the normalization layer and 10 nodes of the previous layer. Is it possible in keras? Do I have to handle tensorflow?

Please help me.. thank you

Here is my code.

```
    train_input_data = input_data[:80000, :]
    train_output_data = output_data[:80000, :]
    test_input_data = input_data[80000:, :]
    test_output_data = output_data[80000:, :]

    X_train, X_test = train_input_data, test_input_data
    y_train, y_test = train_output_data, test_output_data

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4000, input_dim=800, init='glorot_normal'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.7))
    model.add(Dense(2000, init='glorot_normal'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.7))
    model.add(Dense(1000, init='glorot_normal'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.7))
    model.add(Dense(80, init='glorot_normal'))
    model.add(Activation('linear'))
    model.add(Reshape((8, 10)))
    model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=-1)))
    model.add(Reshape((None, 80)))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae', metrics=['mae', min_absolute_error, max_absolute_error])

    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=8192, verbose=1)
    (loss, mean_error, min_error, max_error) = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
```

Comment: Can you post some code about your model? It'll be easier to understand your question with it.

Comment: @Yu-Yang I add a figure of architecture and the code. Please tell me if you still have an unclear part. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Will the code work if you change the last layer into `model.add(Reshape((80,)))`?

Comment: Or you can just use `model.add(Flatten())`. They should be the same.

Comment: @Yu-Yang Thank you! It works. I learned a lot thanks to you :).

Comment: @Yu-Yang Is it okay to ask one more question? Since the shape before the normalization layer is (8,10), the axis of the normalization layer should be 0 (in order to normalize 10 nodes)? If axis = 0, then normalize is done along the row.

Comment: The shape before the normalization layer is in fact `(batch_size, 8, 10)`. In a `Reshape` layer, the axis for the batch size is ignored. But in a `Lambda` layer it is not. So for `K.l2_normalize`, you have 3 choices: `axis=0`, `axis=1` and `axis=2` (or `axis=-1`, they are the same). Since you want to normalize 10 nodes, the `axis` argument should be 2 or -1.

Comment: The `axis` argument is a bit difficult to understand. I kind of think of it as the axis that will be "looped over" if the operation is implemented with for loops. So to normalize 10 nodes, the for loop needs to go over `axis=2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this seems to answer your question, but the last part of it is very unclear. "Node" and "fully connected" are terms that mean "each pass through a layer in the graph" and "dense layer".

You can, though, reorganize your features in groups of ten:

```
#suppose the original output shape is (None, dim1, dim2, features)    
#where features is a multiple of 10.

#add:
Reshape((dim1,dim2,features//10,10))
Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=-1))
Reshape((dim1,dim2,features//10))
```

For a case with only the features dimension:

```
#original shape is (None, features)

#add
Reshape((features//10,10))
Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=-1))
Reshape((features//10,))
```

Comment: I add figure of architecture. Please tell me if you still have an unclear part. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A normalization layer alone doesn't reduce dimensions. How are you expecting to transform 80 outputs in 8?

Comment: I want to normalize each of 10 dimensions in output layer. In this case, can not I implement using one node of the normalization layer per 10 nodes of the previous layer?

Comment: When 80 units of output are grouped into 10 units, the sum of squares of 10 units must be 1.

Comment: I think my last comment was totally wrong.... sorry. But then, my answer will do what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I use model.summary(), but I don't know mean of dim1, dim2. Is there any way I can figure out?

Comment: Dim1 and Dim2 are not necessarily there. I gave an example for an arbitrary tensor. Just to show that it will act only in the last dimension (the dimension that is important to you). If your model doesn't have more than the last dimension, ok, remove dim1 and dim2 from the example. It can be `(None, features)`.

Comment: Thank you very much :). I am learning a lot because of you.  I got an error and attached the code above. my error is below.
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
If I do reshape ((8,)) as you said last, does the output shape have an error because it does not have the original shape (None, 80)??

Comment: The total number of elements must be the same before and after the reshape. (You can't add numbers or discard, you just regroup them in different forms). The array with shape `(None, 80)` has ? * 80 elements.